# HTML page in MVC not updating a c# global variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I'm almost ready to go in making my crappy website, but my html p's aren't updating their values when I submit my forms, my controllers do the updating but it just does not show on the web page, I think I am missing something where the values get updated, but here's the code so you can better understand:

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@using vgsimulator.Models

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Album ka = new Album();

}

<h2>Search</h2>

<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("filter")

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
</div>

<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "SearchForm" }))
{

    @Html.RadioButton("color", "red", new { id = "isRed" })
    @Html.RadioButton("color", "blue", new { id = "isBlue" })
    @Html.RadioButton("color", "green", new { id = "isGreen" })
    <button type="submit" />
}
</div>


<div>

<p>@ViewBag.Sup</p>
<p>@ViewBag.Query</p>

</div>



<div>

<p>@ka.kkk</p>
<p>@ka.kkk2</p>


</div>
```

Okay so what this view basically does is it has a text and a radio input, and displays in p's, the values of my global variables 'kkk' and 'kkk2' which their default values are : 'unModified' and 'unTouched'.

Model(Album.cs):

```
  public string kkk = "unModified";

  public string kkk2 = "unTouched";
```

So this model just set's global variables.

Controller (HomeController):

```
public ActionResult Index(string filter)
    {
        Album kk = new Album();
        kk.kkk2 = "notFire";

        if (filter == "fire")
        {
            ViewBag.Query = filter;
            kk.kkk2 = filter; //updated value
        }


        return View("Index"); 
    }


    public ActionResult Search(string color)
    {
        Album kk = new Album();

        if (color == "red")
        {
            ViewBag.Sup = "red chosen!";
            kk.kkk = "red chosen!"; //updated value
        }



        return View("Index"); 

    }
```

So the controller now updates my global variable values, all good and done, but run this crap and when I start inputting, my updated values are not shown... weird, I'm assuming I am missing a function in here that when I input/submit form values, my c# values also update, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing your model to the view. As a result, the view is newing up an `Album` for you. The only reason this works at all and doesn't fail with a runtime exception is because you have default values, which is all that is every being displayed. Just change your return line to:

```
return View("Index", kk);
```

**EDIT**

Actually, your view isn't using a model *at all* and *you* are the one newing up an `Album` instance in the view. As a result, in addition to what I said above, you need to add a model declaration to the top of your view:

```
@model vgsimulator.Models.Album
```

Then, later:

```
<p>@Model.kkk</p>
<p>@Model.kkk2</p>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, when running, it still did not update the values on the page :/ but I feel like I'm getting closer

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new album object, then setting the value of kkk amd then throwing the object away when your code returns. There is no global variable here.